# Get PFUser object custom values

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfuser

I have custom value in a PFUser column called `"website"`. I am trying to get this value using the code below but it does not seem to change on the device if I update the value from Parse.com on their website using the data viewer. It also does not update across devices.
Any Ideas?

`websiteField.text = currentUser.objectForKey("website") as String`

Comment: Have you refreshed the `currentUser` object since updating it on their website? You'll need to manually do that.

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to get it working with the code below.

```
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    currentUser.refreshInBackgroundWithBlock { (object, error) -> Void in
        println("Refreshed")
        currentUser.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock { (result, error) -> Void in

            self.websiteStr = currentUser.objectForKey("website") as String
            self.websiteField.text = self.websiteStr

            println("Updated")

            println(self.websiteStr)
        }
    }
```

Comment: currentUser.refresh seems to no longer be available in Parse 1.6.0. Use .fetch() instead