# Swift Parse: can not retrieve the value of a bool in _User class

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform

I am developing an app using swift and Parse. For some reasons I have implemented a Bool named "modified" in the _User class. I have been playing around with swift and Parse for a few months but this just does not make sense.

When I try to retrieve the value of the "modified" Bool I keep on getting "false" value even though it is set on "true" on Parse server. Here is the code:

```
    var modified: Bool = PFUser.currentUser().objectForKey("modified") as! Bool
    println("User Modified Bool is set to: \(modified)")
```

I have also tried with

```
    self.modified = PFUser.currentUser().valueForKey("modified") as! Bool
    println("User Modified Bool is set to: \(modified)")
```

and

```
    self.modified = PFUser.currentUser()["modified"] as! Bool
    println("User Modified Bool is set to: \(modified)")
```

Do I have to make a specific query or is there a way to access this value directly?

**Edit**

I have implemented a specific query. Still get a "false" value though

```
        var queryMainUser: PFQuery = PFUser.query()
    queryMainUser.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().username)
    queryMainUser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (mainUsersObjects, mainUsersError) -> Void in
        if (mainUsersError == nil) {
            var theRef = mainUsersObjects[0] as! PFObject
            self.modified = theRef["modified"] as! Bool
            println("Any improvement? \(self.modified)")
        }
    }
```

**Edit 2**

Following @danh advices, I tried updating the currentuser instance on the device by implementing this code:

```
        var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    currentUser.fetchInBackgroundWithBlock { (object, error) -> Void in
        println("Refreshed")
        currentUser.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock { (result, error) -> Void in

            self.modified = currentUser.objectForKey("modified") as! Bool
            var idOfUser: String = currentUser.objectId
            println("User \(idOfUser) UPDATED")
            println(self.modified)
            if self.modified == true {
                self.deleteData()
                self.fetchAllObjects()
            }
        }
    }
```

When running the console gives me this:

```
Refreshed
User xTbBw6cNzK UPDATED
false
```

Here is a screenshot I just took of the server side:
[image: can't get bool from Parse]

Thank you all for your attention

Comment: Are you sure its the syntax on getting the col?  Maybe the user is out of date.  After the flag is set in the cloud, you'd need to use some form of refresh (e.g. http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/refreshInBackgroundWithBlock:) in order to have it current.  Also, please note that PFObject implements `isDirty()` which might be a built-in version of the function that you're trying to create.

Comment: hello @danh, thank you for your answer. I have looked at the `isDirty()` you mentioned. But it is not exactly what I need. I use the "modified" bool to tell the user to refresh its friends list. This bool is modified on the server when a new friends relationship is implemented. 
I am sorry but I do not really understand what you mean by "out of date".

Comment: The current user is a proxy for the user in the database.  If you've changed some attribute of the server-sdie user in cloud code, it won't be represented by the client copy (currentUser) unless you do a refresh.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @danh. I did not know that. I have refreshed the user by implementing the solution given in this post [et PFUser object custom valuse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284575/get-pfuser-object-custom-valuse)

But I still get "false" while the value is clearly true on the server.

Comment: The answer you refer to looks right to me (though I'm iffy in swift).  It might make sense to update your question, presenting evidence that the cloud user is saved along with the value of the "modified" flag you expect, and after a refresh *of that same user* on the client, the flag is different.  (I'm betting you'll figure out your problem as you collect that evidence).

Comment: Using the latest Parse SDK, your objectForKey call should work fine after you make a call to PFUser.currentUser().fetch(). Are you sure you're changing the correct user on the Parse server? Print the objectId from PFUser.currentUser and compare to the objectId on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what version of swift you are using. But if you are using Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7, this SHOULD do the job.

This will not work:

```
let modifiedStatus = PFUser.currentUser()?["modified"] // return value will be nil
```

This will work for sure:

```
let modifiedStatus = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("modified")
print(modifiedStatus) // true as per your table
```

I know this may sound strange, but some I struggle with something for hours later realising my silly mistake. So it is always good to move back of the current task and later recheck after few hours. So just make sure you cross check the following:

- The key "modified" in the main user class of parse
- You can retrieve other key values (just to see if nothing else is wrong other than your current retrieving of a key bool value(

Though I am on Swift 2.0, but for sure there is no major change from in this specific code when it comes to move from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2.0.

Just see and if it still doesn't work, we can discuss more on your setup.

Answer (score 0):

I have initialised a "doneSetUp" var as a local variable, it is an int.
then I query the user which just logged in
checks if it exists...
check if the variable userDidSetUp exists in parse and if it does I am converting it to an int and assign it to the local variable doneSetUp I made
then I am using the "doneSetUp" variable which now has a value of 0(false) or 1(true) to decide if the user already setup his account or not and then segue the user to the correct view controller.
mention that all of this code is inside of my logininbackgroundwithblock function.
I hope that helped.

```
query?.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(user!.objectId!, block: {
                    (user, error) -> Void in

                    if let user = user{

                        if var userDidSetUp: AnyObject = user["doneSetUp"] {

                            self.doneSetUp = userDidSetUp as! Int

                            if self.doneSetUp == 0 {

                                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("procceedToSetup", sender: self)

                            }else{

                                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("procceedToApp", sender: self)

                            }


                        }

                    }

                })
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post, but here's what worked for me.
This is inside the viewDidLoad method.

```
PFUser.currentUser()?.fetchInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object, error) -> Void in

        var modified = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("modified")?.boolValue

        if modified == true {

            print(modified) // Output console displays "true"
```

Hope this helps.